The two tables are join using a hash join without substr in the join condition.Why does substr appear in the predicate information?
ENV: ORACLE DB 19.20 VERSION
Test case

Create table and index.

SQL> create table t100 as select * from dba_objects;
SQL> create index idx_substr_object_name on t100 (substr(object_name,1,4));
SQL> create index idx_object_name on t100(object_name);
SQL> create table t200 as select * from dba_objects;
SQL> create index idx_t200 on t200(object_name);


Query with use_hash hint and get the real execution plan.

SQL> select /*+use_hash(a) use_hash(b)*/ count(*) from t100 a,t200 b where a.object_name=b.object_name;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    705590

SQL> set lines 1000 pages 1000

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(FORMAT=>'ADVANCED'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  bpkc4rb5vu9y3, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+use_hash(a) use_hash(b)*/ count(*) from t100 a,t200 b where
a.object_name=b.object_name

Plan hash value: 3047534014

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |         |   |   |   |   696 (100)|      |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |         |     1 |    76 |   |        |      |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN        |         |   111K|  8294K|  3792K|   696   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| IDX_T200    | 86239 |  2779K|   |   143   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| IDX_OBJECT_NAME | 86159 |  3618K|   |   143   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("A"."OBJECT_NAME"="B"."OBJECT_NAME" AND
          SUBSTR("OBJECT_NAME",1,4)=SUBSTR("B"."OBJECT_NAME",1,4)) 

Question:
Why is "SUBSTR("OBJECT_NAME",1,4)=SUBSTR("B"."OBJECT_NAME",1,4))" displayed in the "Predicate Information"?

It looks like a bit of optimizer intelligence. Oracle frequently adds predicates it knows are guaranteed logically to produce the same results, if it thinks those predicates can help with performance. The most frequent is where it adds a "IS NOT NULL" to an inner join column of a nullable column since it knows no NULL join key will produce a result, thus potentially shrinking the size of a hash join input. This one you found is probably similar.
You created a function-based index on SUBSTR(object_name,1,4). Not only do you have an index that might be useful if you add a matching predicate (a preparation that might take place before it chooses which index to actually use), but you have a hidden virtual column for it (see user_tab_cols) may have a statistic extension for it as well (user_stat_extensions), and those statistics may be useful in some way in the optimizer's later computations. It doesn't have to actually be helpful; it makes sense even if it might have been helpful had the optimizer gone a different direction later in its plan development.

Yes, you are right that ORACLE optimizer is doing the transformation internally, but I couldn't find the documentation to explain this phenomenon.

@binwam You asked Why is "SUBSTR("OBJECT_NAME",1,4)=SUBSTR("B"."OBJECT_NAME",1,4))" displayed in the "Predicate Information"?, which I tried to answer, not where it is in documentation. You won't find it or any other optimizer intelligence documented anywhere, it's proprietary logic that Oracle doesn't publish. We can make educated guesses, however, based on experience and observation.
